# unable to get correct path of a video

Tags: android, video, media

I want my application to pick a video from the gallery. It uses following code to get the path.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
i.setType("video/*"); 
startActivityForResult(i,2);
```

and then

```
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){

      str = data.getData().getPath();
   //this.go();
      this.ko();
  }
 }
```

`str` stores the path. For a test run its value is `/external/video/media/10` but it should be something like `/sdcard/DCIM/a.mp4` to load the video using `MediaMetaDataRetriever`. How to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, (As I understand your question)

```
if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
      str = getRealPathFromURI(data.getData());
   //this.go();
      this.ko();
  }
```

Use, this function to get Real path from the Uri..

**Function:**

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri)
    {
        try
        {
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return contentUri.getPath();
        }
    }
```